# Queryset inside et ouside a function

Tags: django, function, django-queryset

Assume, in the database, `withdrawal=12`. If, in a function, I define a queryset, e.g., `OBJECT.objects.get(withdrawal=17)`, am I right to say that, if I don't save in the function, withdrawal=17, and once I am out  of the function, withdrawal becomes again equal to 12?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear, if withdrawal has a value of 12 in the db then you obviously won't be able to get one with a value of 17,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OBJECT.objects.get(withdrawal=17)` is a query and does not change the data stored in your database. It will return exactly one instance of type `OBJECT` if there is exactly one, otherwise it will raise an error.

If you want to get all instances of type OBJECT where `withdrawal` is set to `17` then use:

```
OBJECT.objects.filter(withdrawal=17)
```

If you want to modify all instances that have a `withdrawal` of `12` to have the new value `17` use:

```
OBJECT.objects.filter(withdrawal=12).update(withdrawal=17)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update

If you want to know more about functions and expressions that allow for more complex queries and modifications check out this part of the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/